# jquery timepicker now button and current date selecting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using TimePicker plugin on my webapp: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/
It works great, except that default behaviour for "Now" button is not what I want to.

As for normal DatePicker I found this piece of code which works great:

```
jQuery.datepicker._gotoToday = function ( id )
{
    var target = jQuery( id );
    var inst = this._getInst( target[0] );
    if ( this._get( inst, 'gotoCurrent' ) && inst.currentDay )
    {
        inst.selectedDay = inst.currentDay;
        inst.drawMonth = inst.selectedMonth = inst.currentMonth;
        inst.drawYear = inst.selectedYear = inst.currentYear;
    }
    else
    {
        var date = new Date();
        inst.selectedDay = date.getDate();
        inst.drawMonth = inst.selectedMonth = date.getMonth();
        inst.drawYear = inst.selectedYear = date.getFullYear();
        this._setDateDatepicker( target, date );
        this._selectDate( id, this._getDateDatepicker( target ) );
    }
    this._notifyChange( inst );
    this._adjustDate( target );
};
```

Unfortunatelly not for TimePicker. Could some one provide me similar code I could use for TimePicker plugin?

Comment: how do you want it to work like

Comment: Normal functionality of "Now" button is to go back on calendar to curerent date. With code I pasted it instead selects "Now" date to desired input. It works for datepicker from jQuery UI but not from TimePicker pluging. I want it to work same way -> selecting current date with time to input